# Declare encoding in Open AI Gym implementation on Python 3

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am learning reinforcement learning and following [this](https://gym.openai.com/docs/#background-why-gym-2016) tutorial.  I am trying to run an instance of CartPole-v0 environment and getting this error.

```
import gym
env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
env.reset()
for _ in range(1000):
    env.render()
    env.step(env.action_space.sample())

SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file /home/kshitizsahay26/gym/gym/envs/classic_control/cartpole.py on line 27, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

I read that the default encoding in Python 3 is UTF-8 but it doesn't seem so in this case. I looked up at the URL mentioned in the error message but it 's applicable for Python 2.6. How should I change the encoding in this script?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this error by adding:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

to the beginning of cartpole.py file